# How to fix 'multithreading problem' in python in rasberry pi

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi3

I couldn't find out what might be the problem with the multithreading program that I have written in python in raspberry pi 3 for the object recognition.

The code is running on the raspberry pi 3 model. I am hoping to make two threads; one is for showing the live images and another is to detect an object and find its center. I tried the code that I have written below. It works fine when I use it in laptop but it doesn't work ( the second function; detect() doesn't responds after the line  faces = drop_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, 1.25, 7)) on the raspberry pi but if i remove that line and following for loop and replace with simple code such as print( "hello") it works fine.

```py
import threading
import cv2
import numpy as np
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
global image, center
center=[]
def capture():
    global image, center
    cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.moveWindow('image',0,0)
    cv2.resizeWindow('image', 800,608)
    camera=PiCamera()
    camera.resolution=(800,608)
    camera.framerate=50
    rawCapture=PiRGBArray(camera,size=(800,608))
    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture,format='bgr',use_video_port=True):
        image=frame.array      
        cv2.imshow('image',image)

        key=cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
        if key==ord('q'):
            break    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def detect():
    global image, center
    time.sleep(2)
    drop_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')
    while True:
        faces = drop_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, 1.25, 7)
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            center.append([x,y,w,h])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread1=threading.Thread(target=capture)
    thread2=threading.Thread(target=detect)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
```

I want to run these thread simultaneously so that the image showed by capture function run smoothly and detection is done by the detect function.

Comment: Edit question to explain "doesn't work" in detail.